# How much tax does a French taxpayer have to pay for donations received via crowdfunding platforms (e.g., GoFundMe)

Tags: taxes, france

How much tax does a French taxpayer have to pay for donations received via crowdfunding platforms (e.g., [GoFundMe](https://www.gofundme.com) ([mirror](https://www.gofundme.com)))?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Because being french we asssume you know how to calculate your income tax. GoFundMe Donations are NOT donations, they are income for the receiver. Normal income.

Comment: @TomTom "Being french we asssume you know how to calculate your income tax." lol, seriously?

Comment: If the enterprise is set up with the state as a company with shares of stock then the company is just funded with cash exchanged for shares of stock. There is no income. The state might have a yearly net-worth tax that applies to businesses.

Comment: @TomTom Do you likewise downvote every question about the IRS because "_being American, we assume [they: the askers] know how to calculate [their] income tax_"? Downvoting for not showing any research that might have been done is another matter...